# How to override core catalog block in product view page

Tags: magento-1.8, blocks, overrides

Hi i'm newbie to magento, trying to override catalog price block to use my custom price.phtml (Coz it's conflicting if i do any css updates). To do this I have done below steps,

Copied `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product.php`

In the copied file, about Line 61, changed

```
public function getPriceHtml($product)
    {
        $this->setTemplate('catalog/product/price.phtml');
        $this->setProduct($product);
        return $this->toHtml();
    }
```

to

```
public function getPriceHtml($product)
    {
        $this->setTemplate('catalog/product/customprice.phtml');
        $this->setProduct($product);
        return $this->toHtml();
    }
```

Is there any further config required to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do changes in theme(in phtml files), it is better to create your own theme and copy price.phtml in your theme and do necessary changes.
Create your theme under app/design/frontend/default/[YOUR THEME]/ and copy your file in your custom theme like app/design/frontend/default/[YOUR THEME]/template/catalog/product/price.phtml 
And select your theme in admin-end System -> Configuration -> General -> Design

http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/working-with-magento-themes

http://blog.belvg.com/create-custom-themes-magento-front-end-developer-certification.html

Answer (score 0):

**Do not do this!!!**. Don't just copy and edit core files.
  http://panphoenix.com/blog/magento-developing-101-never-use-appcodelocalmage-to-override-core-files/,
http://magebase.com/magento-articles/when-should-you-override-magento-core-files-in-app_code_local_mage/.
Create your own module and than override the block.Here are some links to guide you on how to do it: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-part10-series-overriding, http://magentocustom.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-override-magento-block-classes.html, http://prattski.com/2010/06/24/magento-overriding-core-files-blocks-models-resources-controllers/